# Same domain but two different companies hosting separate email addresses?

Tags: email, domain, mx-record

Is it possible for my company to have G suite host one email address
while another company hosts the other addresses.

e.g john@somedomain.com hosted by **G Suite** and contact@somedomain.com hosted by another company?

Would there be a conflict with the MX records potentially?

Any information would be appreciated!

Comment: You can't do this with MX records so you'll need to look into using SMTP namespace sharing, if both email systems support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't really do this with MX records. If you add MX records for both hosts, then you will either end up with all (or almost all) email going to one, or emails being split between both hosts, depending on the MX priority numbers you use.

MX works solely based on the domain so you can't have an MX record that only applies to a single address.

If email for `someone@somedomain.com` ends up at "other host", and you've only set up `contact@somedomain.com` on their servers, it will likely just be rejected as an unknown recipient.

Not sure what forwarding options you have in G Suite, but the most simple option is to have everything go there (with MX all set as specified by Google), and just forward `contact@somedomain.com` to `contact@somesubdomain.somedomain.com`. Then set up MX records for the subdomain pointing at the other host. Unless that host has strict sender restrictions you can likely still use `contact@somedomain.com` as the sender address (definitely as a reply-to address) when setting up that account in a mail client.